# Get HTML colour code of a colour from a .png file?

Tags: html, colors

I have a .png file containing a colour, is it possible to find it's equivalent HTML color code using any Tool/Software/Website?

Comment: @j08691 I am completely new to web development and have absolutely no idea at all.

Comment: Do you want to do it with a software or with javascript?

Comment: @Mageek Anything would be fine. But a javascript is obviously more preferable.

Comment: I have one, wait a little bit.

Comment: @myselfpoddar If `a javascript is obviously more preferable` why did you accept a non-javascript?

Comment: @Mageek JavaScript is more preferable as it is simpler to use and also more secure. And I had accepted the answer before you had posted your first comment here. Anyhow, I would change it now.

Comment: What? How is JavaScript "more preferable" when all you need is a stupid colorpicker? I assume you're on Windows, so just go ahead and download Paint.NET or IrfanView. They're excellent image manipulation tools, can open PNG, and one of the features is an eye dropper (color picker) which will show you the hex code of the color, which you can then plug into HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the js:

```
var x=0,y=0;//Coordinates of the pixel of which you want to have the color

var img=new Image();
img.onload=function()
{
    var canvas=document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.setAttribute("width",1);
    canvas.setAttribute("height",1);
    canvas.setAttribute("style","display:none;");
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    var ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.drawImage(img,x-1,y-1);
    var pixels=ctx.getImageData(0,0,1,1);
    var r=pixels.data[0];
    var g=pixels.data[1];
    var b=pixels.data[2];
    var a=pixels.data[3];
    alert("rgb("+r+", "+g+", "+b+")\nrgba("+r+", "+g+", "+b+", "+a+")\n");
}
img.src="../img/logo.png";
```

And a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Sqjj9/5/

Answer (score 0):

You could use a tool like [Color Spy](http://download.cnet.com/Color-Spy/3000-10247_4-10161718.html) to get color codes from an image.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the firefox addon 'colorzilla'.

http://www.colorzilla.com/

It features an eyedropper that when used, the HTML color will be copied and can then be pasted somewhere as #xxxxxx.